# How to extend chrome browser to dual display on fullscreen

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

I am trying to figure out how to make the browser to cover both displays (on a dual-screen setup, with same resolution on both screens) on Fullscreen mode under MS Windows.

I have checked the developer tools, but that only emulates the display. 
Some MS Windows utilities do offer this feature but it doesn't work for Google Chrome browser. And also its not fullscreen mode.

If there isn't any chrome-extension available, can you point out if this is possible through writing a chrome-extension ?
Any pointers are more than welcome.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working using nVidia desktop mosaic feature. 
Still looking for driver independent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Move your windows to the left screen and place your mouse cursor on the left end of the window and press + hold and pull to stretch it, that would extend to the next screen as well and it would stay until u close the windows. 
Note : you would need to perform this for every windows and application individually.

Comment: It didn't quite work like that for me, but got me messing around. If I dock the window to the left (WinKey+Left Arrow), so it's only using half the screen, this works (maybe that's what you meant?)