# Chrome kiosk or fullscreen in extended mode screen (two monitors)

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, multiple-monitors, kiosk-mode

Is it possible to make a Chrome window display in kiosk mode on two monitors in Windows 7?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is 3 years old but since this is still one of the first results in google search for this topic, I thought it wouldn't hurt to point out that you can accomplish this if you have a normal nVidia gtx card (no need for a Quadro/mosaic), by going to the nVidia control panel, on the left click on `Configure surround, physx` and then `configure` in the `Configure surround` section.

From there you can enable the nVidia surround feature which will make windows believe it has one monitor with a custom resolution (which will be the sum of your multiple monitors res). If you have 3 1920x1080 monitors it will show a single monitor with a resolution of 5760x1080. Once you've done that you just have to enable kiosk mode like always and chrome will open up as expected, with a single ultrawide full-screen window across all the three displays.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Alir user said in that post ([How to extend chrome browser to dual display on fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234534/how-to-extend-chrome-browser-to-dual-display-on-fullscreen?rq=1)) it could be done with nVidia desktop mosaic feature on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

AMD graphic card users have option to create one monitor too in AMD catalyst center under Multiple monitor option.
Then all you need to do is press F11 in Chrome and display page across all monitors.